# slideToggle with table show and hide

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle, jquery-effects

This closes previous menu entry when I click on a new entry, but this
does not work when I click the same entry again, menu stays open.

I don't know how the syntax is to check if previous and current entry are the
same and only do the hide.

```
    $(document).on("click", ".library-item-title", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var entry_id = $(this).data("id");
    toggleDropdown(entry_id);
});

function toggleDropdown(entry_id) {
    $(".library-edit-dropdown").hide("slow");
    $("#library-edit-dropdown-" + entry_id).show("slow");
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/patelmilanb1/LzaZT/1/

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `toggle` and `not` methods:

```
function toggleDropdown(entry_id) {
    $(".library-edit-dropdown")
     .not( $("#library-edit-dropdown-" + entry_id).toggle("slow") )
     .hide("slow");
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wqtuy0mx/

Note that above query can be expensive. You are using event delegation, probably this means you are generating the elements dynamically, but if caching is possible, you should cache the collection and reuse it.

Answer (score -1):

use this script.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$('tr.parent')
    .css("cursor","pointer")
    .attr("title","Click to expand/collapse")
    .click(function(){
        $(this).siblings('.child-'+this.id).toggle("show");
    });
$('tr[@class^=child-]').hide().children('td');
});
</script>
```

and use this in parent element  in the table.

```
class="parent" id="main_someid"
```

and this in child  in the table.

```
 class="child-main_someid"
```

it worked for me. you can lood it by giving itereated someid variable.
check the fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/makicool/LzaZT/2/